# Calculating $\sin{\pi x}$ in a weird way

Tags: complex-numbers

Got bored in math class and found out that $$\sin{\pi x} = \frac{imag((-x)^x)}{real(x^x)}$$ for x > 0. Can anybody please proove to me that the above equation is true? (Because I myself can't)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $x$ real ? There is no consensus on the meaning of a negative raised to a power.

Comment: How could you obtain this if you can't prove it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust experimenting

Comment: How can you "experiment" this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

express $(-x)^x$ in the form $a+ib$ and you will find that it contains the trig term $sin(\pi x)$. Once you divide this expression by $x^x$ you will arrive at the result you are trying to prove. Tip: You will need to use DeMoivre's Theorem.

Comment: Thanks man! Kind of expected that my equation isn't as original as i thought.